# The "Delete" button on comments now always shows instead of only on hover; is this an intentional change?

Tags: support, design, comments

I've noticed that the "Delete" button on my own comments now always shows, instead of being shown only when I mouse over the comment as before.

I personally like the change, as it makes it friendlier to touchscreen users as they don't have to tap once to see the button and a second time to click it.

However, changes to commonly-used features without any type of notice are kind of jarring, especially when one's gotten used to the old UI, and often raise questions as to whether the new behavior is a bug. For all I know, this change could have been accidental as a result of another change and subject to be reverted (also without notice).

So I'm asking now: is this an intentional change or a bug? Also, why was this change not announced (e.g., as an edit to the [changelog post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange))?

**Update:** I can only sporadically reproduce. I refreshed a page that had the buttons always showing up, and now they're showing only on hover again. I did the same to the same page a while later, and they were again always showing up. I think this is an A/B test, or it could be something that got pushed, reverted, pushed again, etc. I tested with all extensions and user scripts disabled.

This is on a touchscreen laptop, using Windows 11 and Edge.

Comment: Crucial part of such bug reports is to share what browser and OS you're using, and userscripts as well. I can't reproduce as well, seeing the delete only when hovering. Edit was always visible as far as I remember, didn't require hover.

Comment: @Laurel I'm on a touchscreen laptop, using Windows 11 and Edge.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I just tried using Edge on Windows 11, but it didn't display anything. Might have something to do with touchscreen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The class `hover-only-label` is designed to behave one way on a desktop and another on touch/mobile devices.

On a normal desktop, the `Delete` link is shown as hidden by default, as you can see in this CSS:

[image: visibility:hidden on desktop]

And on `focus-within` (which works like `hover` for reasons I did not dig into):

[image: visibility:visible on focus on desktop]

You can use developer tools / toggle device emulation to re-render the page as if you were on a mobile device. In this case you will see that the `Delete` link is always visible, and the CSS has become:

[image: visibility:visible always on mobile]

Your browser/user agent must identify in such a way that it returns true for the property `@media (hover: none)`. What is the full user agent [shown here](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+my+user+agent)?

Comment: I think the fault is in my browser for sometimes incorrectly reporting the value. What I figured out is that the button begins to always show up when I fold my 2-in-1 laptop into a tablet, and then again only show up on hover once I fold it back into a laptop. The problem here was *not* merely that, however, as the whole time I was testing, I never folded my laptop into a tablet and always tested in the same mode. Most likely conclusion is that Edge's implementation is sometimes buggy and doesn't correctly return `hover` at times.